# Session Handling for in WCF for ASP.net Client

Tags: wcf

I have a asp.net client for a WCF Service . WCF Service is PerSession. How to maintain WCF Service Session for different asp.net pages ?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you want a different WCF session for each page visited by a particular ASP.NET client session; or are you asking how to align the WCF session with the ASP.NET session, so the client gets the same WCF session regardless of which page is requested?

Comment: yes i want to align the WCF session with the ASP.NET session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it the session will be maintained in the ASP.Client only and not the WCF Service. That is you will manage all of your state in your client only.

Answer (score 1):

well you can do that by sending session id in Header when calling to WCF service.